# ImportError: No module named captchia.fields

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 django 1.11 and django simple captcha 0.56,
when I using python manage.py test captcha, error popup as below,

---

### [image]

appreciated if any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieved to have 2 typos in 1 import

```
from captcha.fields  import CaptchaField
```

On line 18 of /django-app/expo/registration/forms.py

Comment: Thank, iklinac. Another error come out now. 
[code] File "/Users/wzy/django-app/expo/registration/forms.py", line 18, in <module>
    from captcha.fields import CapchaField
ImportError: cannot import name CapchaField

Comment: @wupeter that is your second typo look at my answer CaptchaField

Comment: Thanks iklinac, you are correct. Now the problem is truly fixed. Many thanks.